# Azure VM turn on and off from inside itself

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-cli, azure-vm

The end goal is to create a Jenkins job that starts an Azure VM on and then turn it off. I have seen commands online that state how to turn VMs on and off. I have a master Windows VM. Can I start this VM from inside itself using Azure CLI? If it can be done then I can add it into Windows batch command of Jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I start this VM from inside itself using Azure CLI?

As far as I know, Azure VM is based on hyper-v virtualization technology refer to [this](https://www.quora.com/What-technology-is-Azure-running-on-Is-it-on-Hyper-V-or-some-other-kind-of-virtualization-technology). I don't think you can start a virtualization machine from VM itself whatever it's using Azure CLI or not. You need to start it from hyper-v host or hyper-v management UI.

The `Run Command` feature uses the virtual machine (VM) agent to run PowerShell scripts within an Azure Windows VM. I have tried the Azure windows VM, I can stop or start Azure VM but for deallocated VM, I can not start it using this method.

```
az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name <vmname> -g <vmrg>  --scripts 'shutdown /s /t 0' 
    
az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name <vmname> -g <vmrg>  --scripts 'restart'
```

If you don't from VM itself. Usually, you can use [Azure CLI 2.0: Quickly Start / Stop ALL VMs](https://build5nines.com/azure-cli-2-0-quickly-start-stop-all-vms/),

```
# usage example
az vm start --name MyVM --resource-group MyVMGroup

az vm deallocate --name MyVM --resource-group MyVMGroup

az vm stop --name MyVM --resource-group MyVMGroup
```

Moreover, for Azure VM, the [Start/Stop VMs during off-hours feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management) make you start or stops enabled Azure VMs. You could refer to [this blog](https://www.ntweekly.com/2019/03/16/how-to-schedule-azure-vms-to-turn-on-and-off-using-azure-automation/) for more details.

Comment: How can I start/stop VM agent from Jenkins?